# Angular - set value on formControl without resetting errors

Tags: angular, forms, validation, setvalue, form-control

I have the following problem with Angular 6:

I'm trying to manually set the errors property on a formControl with `.setErrors()` and setting the value with `.setValue()` afterwards. The setValue method. To my detriment, `.setValue()` re-runs the validation and resets the `errors` property on the formControl to `null`. Like so:

```
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: FormControl;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formControl = new FormControl();
    this.formControl.setErrors({required: true});
    this.formControl.setValue('foo'); // resets formControl.errors to null
    console.log(this.formControl.errors); // returns null
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured it out. You can use `.disable()` to disable the automatic validation on the formControl - works great if you're using the formControl in an abstract way, as in my case.

```
import { OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: FormControl;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formControl = new FormControl();
    this.formControl.disable({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
    this.formControl.setErrors({required: true});
    this.formControl.setValue('foo');
    console.log(this.formControl.errors); // returns 'foo'
  }

}
```

You can enable the formControl again with `.enable()`, if you need to interact with it in the template.
See more here https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable